# Video artifact detection tool

Tags: video, video-editing

Problem: I have a very large (>10K) number of small (1-10 sec) videos, generated automatically from cutting up larger movie files. The cutting tool isn't flawless, and occasionally it generates videos which have visual artifacts, or the occasional "green picture only".

Are there any tool out there, which can scan through the entire collection, and detect those with artifacts?

I have tried so far: command-line playback, and looking for STDERR output, but the videos *do* play without decoding error.

In terms of bias, I don't mind false positives (will be reviewed manually), but do mind false negatives.

EDIT answering comments: since I will run this in-house for QA, I'm open to suggestions on ANY platform (win, mac, linux, BSD, C64, whatevs); and can commit 20 hours of dev time, and $200 at most.

Comment: Which OS must be supported? Phrasing suggest something Linux/Unix, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Another thing missing in your question: What's your budget? I doubt such software comes cheap (or even for free).

Comment: Deleted my answer, as it was really just a work-around. In short, you could develop something yourself using ffmpeg and ImageMagick, or perhaps opencv. As well as Izzy's suggestion, maybe some sample "bad frames" may give clues to software that could work. I do work with video-related software, and have had to QC 100s of transcoded files in a previous job. There was no easy substitute for just watching the vids then AFAIK, and I don't think you will find anything for a reasonable price/amount of effort now. Except roll your own automated QC if you think the effort will pay back.

Comment: Neil, may I ask you to kindly add your answer back? If no alternatives present itself, in-house development might also be considered, and I'd be very greatful for recommendations & pointers in that regard.